# Not getting OnStart event log entry in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have the following code for a windows service project.  I have successfully built it and installed it.  When I start it I get an event started in the event log.  However,  I never get the event for "In Onstart" any idea why this is going on?

```
namespace ADServiceCarlos
{
    public partial class ADServiceCarlos : ServiceBase
    {           
        public ADServiceCarlos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AutoLog = true;

            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource")) 
            {         
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource","MyNewLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try after clearing event logs from the EventViewer...

Answer (score 4):

OK, so this may solve your problem. It's hard to tell exactly without being able to see all your code, but [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) - more specifically the "caution" part.

> Do not use the constructor to perform processing that should be in
>   OnStart. Use OnStart to handle all initialization of your service. The
>   constructor is called when the application's executable runs, not when
>   the service runs. The executable runs before OnStart. When you
>   continue, for example, the constructor is not called again because the
>   SCM already holds the object in memory. If OnStop releases resources
>   allocated in the constructor rather than in OnStart, the needed
>   resources would not be created again the second time the service is
>   called.

So everything you are doing to initialise the event log in your constructor should be moved to the `OnStart` event. This will ensure it is create properly each time the service start, which means you should be able to log your `OnStart` event correctly (providing you do it after initialisation)

Comment: tried that, however it didn't work.  I've looked at my code and it looks like several examples I have seen online including the one on the microsoft site.

Comment: I figured that part out but now,  I am using a timer on my service, but I never get to the ticket event.  I have timer1.Enabled = true and timer1.Start() in my OnStart, in my timer1_Tick I just have another event entry but never get that entry.

Comment: @user541597: Your timer issue needs to go as a new question

Comment: @user541597 you could have added your answer for other users experiencing the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what @musefan posted, here is an example. I had to move everything out of the constructor completely.

```
public class ServiceMain : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
    {
        public const string SERVICE_NAME = "ServiceName";

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public ServiceMain()
        {
            // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Component Designer.
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.ServiceName = SERVICE_NAME;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            //Log all unhandled exceptions
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new ServiceMain() };
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                    components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set things in motion so your service can do its work.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //Do your stuff here
        }

        static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
}
```